# Does Vim automatically load filetype-specific plugins for custom filetypes?

Tags: vim, plugins, file-type

I understand that the recommended method for defining filetype-specific behavior in Vim is with `.vim` files and `filetype plugin` option. To add settings for `.html` files, for instance, I would add `filetype plugin on` in my `.vimrc` and add the settings to `~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim`.

All examples of this method that I can find, however, are about popular existing filetypes like `.html` or `.sql`. Would the same fix work for custom-defined file types? Let's say I want to use a new filetype with the extension `.newft`. If I create `~/.vim/ftplugin/newft.vim` with the settings for this new type and load `somefile.newft`, would Vim automatically detect its type and load `newft.vim`?

I'm asking this because this is exactly what I'm doing and it's not working so far. I'd like to know whether this is an error or an expected behavior of Vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:h new-filetype` outlines the different ways to add support for a new filetype.

I recommend method `A` which is as simple as writing the following in `~/.vim/ftdetect/newft.vim`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile  *.newft  set filetype=newft
```

and letting Vim deal with the rest.

Assuming you have `filetype plugin on` in your `~/.vimrc`, the example above will make Vim try to source `~/.vim/ftplugin/newft.vim` each time you read or create a buffer associated with a `*.newft` file or do `:setfiletype newft`/`:set filetype=newft` on an existing buffer.

Comment: What if we want that the new `newft` extends the configuration of a previous defined filetype. How to load the default settings, i.e. the previous filetype settings?

Comment: `runtime ftplugin/previousft.vim`near the top  of `ftplugin/newft.vim` would be my first attempt.